# super not working with class decorators?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-decorators

Lets define simple class decorator function, which creates subclass and adds 'Dec' to original class name only:

```
def decorate_class(klass):
    new_class = type(klass.__name__ + 'Dec', (klass,), {})
    return new_class
```

Now apply it on a simple subclass definition:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Base init'

@decorate_class
class MyClass(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'MyClass init'
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
```

Now, if you try instantiate decorated `MyClass`, it will end up in an infinite loop:

```
c = MyClass()
# ...
# File "test.py", line 40, in __init__
#   super(MyClass, self).__init__()
# RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

It seems, `super` can't handle this case and does not skip current class from inheritance chain.

The question, how correctly use class decorator on classes using `super` ?

Bonus question, how get final class from proxy-object created by `super` ? Ie. get `object` class from `super(Base, self).__init__` expression, as determined parent class defining called `__init__`.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? In Python 3 you can just do `super()`, without explicitly referencing the class.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Python 2.7.13. Same example stucks in infinite recursion even in Python 3.6.1. However, if I do omit `super` arguments as suggested, it starts to work as expected. How can I get `super()` behavior with 2.7 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change the class's `.__name__` attribute, make a decorator that does that.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def decorate_class(klass):
    klass.__name__ += 'Dec'
    return klass

class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Base init')

@decorate_class
class MyClass(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print('MyClass init')
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()

c = MyClass()
cls = c.__class__
print(cls, cls.__name__)
```

**Python 2 output**

```
MyClass init
Base init
<class '__main__.MyClassDec'> MyClassDec
```

**Python 3 output**

```
MyClass init
Base init
<class '__main__.MyClass'> MyClassDec
```

Note the difference in the repr of `cls`. (I'm not sure *why* you'd want to change a class's name though, it sounds like a recipe for confusion, but I guess it's ok for this simple example).

As others have said, an `@decorator` isn't intended to create a subclass. You *can* do it in Python 3 by using the arg-less form of `super` (i.e., `super().__init__()`). And you can make it work in both Python 3 and Python 2 by explicitly supplying the parent class rather than using `super`.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def decorate_class(klass):
    name = klass.__name__
    return type(name + 'Dec', (klass,), {})

class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Base init')

@decorate_class
class MyClass(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print('MyClass init')
        Base.__init__(self)

c = MyClass()
cls = c.__class__
print(cls, cls.__name__)
```

**Python 2 & 3 output**

```
MyClass init
Base init
<class '__main__.MyClassDec'> MyClassDec
```

Finally, if we just call `decorate_class` using normal function syntax rather than as an `@decorator` we can use `super`.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def decorate_class(klass):
    name = klass.__name__
    return type(name + 'Dec', (klass,), {})

class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Base init')

class MyClass(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print('MyClass init')
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()

MyClassDec = decorate_class(MyClass)
c = MyClassDec()
cls = c.__class__
print(cls, cls.__name__)
```

The output is the same as in the last version.

Comment: Thanks. The example in OP is a very simplified real case, just for demonstration purposes. But the main point remained, use class decorator to build a new class from its argument. Bit disappointed it is not possible in Python2, despite decorator's documentation is not too specific in this case. Btw. if I replace `super` with parent class call `Base.__init__`, wouldn't it break in cases of multiple inheritance ?

Comment: @dunrix Yes, doing the explicit `Base.__init__(self)` doesn't work so well in cases where `MyClass` has multiple parents since it will only call the `.__init__` of `Base`. Of course, if `MyClass` only has `Base` as a parent but `Base` has multiple parents (and `Base` and its parents all call `super.__init__ ` in their `.__init__` methods) then everything will be fine.

Comment: @dunrix: My suggestion: don't worry about trying to make this work in Python 2, it reaches its End Of Life in 2020, so you should focus on Python 3 for new code. Sure, write Python 2 code if you need to fix old Python 2 stuff, but don't try to add radical new capabilities to it. And give _serious_ thought about migrating the old code to Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Since your decorator returns an entirely new class with different name, for that class `MyClass` object doesn't even exist. This is not the case class decorators are intended for. They are intended to add additional functionality to an existing class, not outright replacing it with some other class.

Still if you are using Python3, solution is simple -

```
@decorate_class
class MyClass(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'MyClass init'
        super().__init__()
```

Otherwise, I doubt there is any straight-forward solution, you just need to change your implementation. When you are renaming the class, you need to rewrite overwrite `__init__` as well with newer name.

Comment: Yes, it returns new class in a analogous way like function decorators return new functions. By your example and as already pointed out by Daniel Roseman, there is not such issue in Python 3. It is quite confusing, class decorators should not be used as class factories in Py2 but can in Py3 ?

Comment: Well, to elaborate python versions before 3 always had an annoying problem that you specifically need to mention the name of the current class (or parent) in the super (due to misguided implementation of explicit is better than implicit principle). Now what you want to do can't be easily accomplished in python2x. Class decorators provide a simpler (though less powerful) alternative to metaclasses. So similar to metaclasses more often than not, decorators are used to change existing class instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Uh, thanks for explanation. I'm only curious if there is some work-around for Py2, ie. save original `MyClass.__init__` in decorator and manually call it from new class __init__ replacement.

Comment: The main problem is with your decorator solution, is you are using same name for two different classes. So what you doing is equivalent to  this - MyClass = decorate_class(MyClass), so you have a class called 'MyClass' whose parent class name is MyClass too.

Comment: Use the last solution mentioned by @PM2ring

Comment: *The main problem is with your decorator solution, is you are using same name for two different classes* - like function decorators create new functions assigned to original names. I thought this is the purpose of decorators. It just broke principle of least surprise for me, because expected `super` would correctly derive reference for decorated class. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your decorator creates a subclass of the original one. That means that `super(Myclass)` now point to... the original class itself!

I cannot even explain how the 0 arg form of `super` manages to do the job in Python 3, I could not find anything explicit in the reference manual. I assume it must use the class in which it is used at the time of declaration. But I cannot imagine a way to get that result in Python2.

If you want to be able to use `super` in the decorated class in Python 2, you should not create a derived class, but directly modify the original class in place.

For example, here is a decorator that prints a line before and after calling any method:

```
def decorate_class(klass):
    for name, method in klass.__dict__.iteritems(): # iterate the class attributes
        if isinstance(method, types.FunctionType):  # identify the methods
            def meth(*args, **kwargs):        # define a wrapper
                print "Before", name
                method(*args, **kwargs)
                print "After", name
            setattr(klass, name, meth)        # tell the class to use the wrapper
    return klass
```

With your example it gives as expected:

```
>>> c = MyClass()
Before __init__
MyClass init
Base init
After __init__
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's all about behavior of zero argument form of `super` in Python3, which reflects updated class reference. Intuitively expected same behavior in Python2. It looks like class decorator is half-baked in 2.x. On one hand, Python re-assigns return value of decorator to the original class identifier, on the other hand it is not reflected in `super` function and no implicit form for runtime lookup is supported.